# Spree-social and omniauth

Tags: omniauth, spree

I am new to ruby and have spree-ecommerce application on spree .70 . I am trying to add Facebook Authentication using spree-social. Install request fails , when I follow exact [steps](https://github.com/spree/spree_social). Here is what I get:

```
Could not load 'omniauth'. Please ensure you have the omniauth gem >= 1.0.0 installed and listed in your Gemfile.
```

I see same error even after running gem install omniauth

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I resolved it by watching the video tutorial at this address http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth. It shows an introduction to OmniAuth.